# Open file in another app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

My app needs to open some file types in other apps, like dropbox app does, it could list the installed apps which could open specific types of file.

How can get the app list?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll want to use [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html). See also the [Document Interaction Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403).

Comment: @DongshengCai: I think you should mark this answer of jtbandes as the correct answer instead of Sony answer.

Comment: Can you please help me with "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613645/add-edit-in-exel-or-edit-photo-extension"

Answer (score 5):

You can use  [QLPreviewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from the official docs.

Comment: Thanks Sony, this is useful too

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on jtbandes's answer, here's the code that worked for me:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
UIDocumentInteractionController *popup = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
[popup setDelegate:self];
[popup presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

And don't forget to include this in your H file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
```

Also worth noting: this will open a new fullscreen view that has a Document Viewer, as well as the Share button that offers all the various apps that can open this file.  If you're just looking for the Share popup, equivalent to the [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/), this will do it, but with some extra functionality you may not want.

Comment: Can anybody give an answer in Swift?