# Is it possible to embed an eBook created with iBooks Author inside an app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ibooks, ibook-author

I would like to embed an e-book created with iBooks Author inside an app. Does anybody know if it's possible?

If not, is it possible to add a "link" in my app that opens the e-book?

Comment: I don't think apple would allow this.

Comment: I too am wondering about this.

Comment: You'd have to send it to iBooks as a file, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7156957/312188 for more info about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can export from iBooks author as PDF and then create a wrapper app that will display that PDF inside an app, but the experience will be suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a computer tool called EPUB to pdf to convert the files into PDF. Once that is done im sure you can go on XCODE.

The easiest way to load and display a local pdf file is to use a UIWebview like that:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```