# How to open iba (iBooks Author) books in a iOS app?

Tags: ibooks

Is it possible to parse and read iba books in a iOS app?

Comment: I looking for this answer too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309670/is-it-possible-to-embed-an-ebook-created-with-ibooks-author-inside-an-app

Comment: I try to read file from iBooks Author like epub file. but I have terrible page layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably impossible without a lot of reverse engineering. .iba files are *based* on epub as mr.octobor suggests, but the layout and rendering isn't achieved through normal html, css and javascript as in epub. Apple uses a lot of proprietary code in .iba, particularly to build the widgets.

Baldur Bjarnason laments this fact on this post, where you can get a better understanding of the situation: http://www.baldurbjarnason.com/notes/the-ibooks-builtin-widgets/

The piece by Daniel Glazman linked in that article is useful as well: http://www.glazman.org/weblog/dotclear/index.php?post/2012/01/20/iBooks-Author-a-nice-tool-but